# If $ \tan(20^{\circ}) = p $, find $ \frac{\tan(160^{\circ}) - \tan(110^{\circ})}{1 + \tan(160^{\circ}) \tan(110^{\circ})} $.

Tags: trigonometry

[image: Problem]

I applied the $ \tan(A - B) $-formula to make it $\tan(50^{\circ}) $, then I split it to $ \tan(30^{\circ} + 20^{\circ}) $. My answer came out to be $ \dfrac{\sqrt[3]{p + 1}}{\sqrt[3]{- p}} $, but the actual answer is $ \dfrac{1 - p^{2}}{2 p} $.

Comment: You seem to be mixing radians and degrees.

Comment: I think he had $\frac{\sqrt{3}+3p}{3-\sqrt{3}p}$

Comment: all are in degrees

Comment: @HowDoIMath: I'm pretty sure you put the parens in the wrong spots.

Comment: the ques is correct

Comment: @Aryan is this (see editted title) what you meant to say?

Comment: @MarkFischler I just inserted a missing dollar sign in the title. I think it's another edit that went wrong then

Comment: can i upload a pic

Comment: You mean you really meant to have the differences in tangents divided by $1$ and then add to that the product of tangents? because that is what the original question said.

Answer (score 7):

$$\frac{\tan 160 - \tan 110}{1+\tan 160 \tan 110} = \tan(160 - 110) = \tan 50 = \cot 40 = \frac{1}{\tan 40} \\
\tan 40 = \frac{\tan 20 + \tan 20}{1-\tan^2 20} = \frac{2p}{1-p^2} \\
\frac{\tan 160 - \tan 110}{1+\tan 160 \tan 110} =  \frac{1-p^2}{2p}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that 160 and 110 are both 20 degrees from key reference points (180 and 90, respectively). By a symmetry argument, we can say that $tan(160) = -tan(20) = -p$ and that $tan(110) = -tan(70) = \frac{-1}{tan(20)} = \frac{-1}{p}$.

Now we simply plug in to the given equation:

$$ \frac{-p - \frac{-1}{p}}{1+(-p)\frac{-1}{p}} = \frac{-p + \frac{1}{p}}{2} = \frac{1 - p^2}{2p}$$